# EF Code first with existing MySql database

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

I have created a class which models my existing table in MySql database.  Below is the class:

```
  public class class1
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }

    public int LastName { get; set; }
    public int FirstName { get; set; }

}
```

I have also created a this class.

```
public class Dbo : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<class1> Classs { get; set; }
}
```

I have created my controller. Now when I run the application, I get this error:

```
 MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException was unhandled by user code
  Message=You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    `LastName` int NOT NULL, 
    `Fi' at line 2
  Source=MySql.Data
  ErrorCode=-2147467259
  Number=1064
```

MySql table has this structure:

```
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `LastName` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `FirstName` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT
```

Comment: Code First? This doesn't look like "Code First" to me. The tables already exist, right?

Comment: @spender Thats Code first with existing database. Check http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/327945/Architecture-Guide-ASP-NET-MVC3-Entity-Framework-C. The tables there already exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to error message, EF trying to create Db for you.

If you add null initializer it should work

```
    public class Dbo : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<class1> Classs { get; set; }
        public Dbo()
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<Dbo>(null);
        }
    }
```

Here is another codeproject article and it worked for me: [Using Entity Framework 4.1 Code First with an existing database](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/184133/Using-Entity-Framework-4-1-Code-First-with-an-exis)

Comment: Thanks a lot. You are right. When I checked the StackTrace I noticed that.Now am moving forward to create association though my underlying data has independent tables.